# Android Studio Debugger Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile-development

Recently Android Studio (4.1.1) has started to act strange. I cannot debug things properly because debugger stops on a random breakpoints (I have removed all of them) I have not set any. To reach a specific breakpoint i need to keep clicking **Resume Program** many times. Attaching few images in case it helps.

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: There was a bug when using shipped JRE and upgrading from 4.0 to 4.1+. I suggest you reinstall Android Studio from scratch and it should solves the issue

Comment: Is the debugger set to stop on exceptions? You have an ``Exception`` on both of your example screenshots. Click the ``View Breakpoints`` button (the two red circles on the left side) and check that *Exception Breakpoints* and *Java Exception Breakpoints* aren't checked

Comment: All the breakpoints are removed. It might be a upgrade problem